# Magento Direct SQL New vs Existing Customers

Tags: magento-1.9, sql

I want to run an SQL query to show orders by new customers and existing customers and group them by month.

EDIT:

I now have this script however it only compares the dates if they are exact to the minute, I now need to compare the dates by just the date rather than date and time.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (

SELECT e.grand_total, e.created_at, COUNT( e.increment_id ) AS grand_total1, o.entity_id, o.created_at AS  `last_order_date` 
FROM  `mg_sales_flat_order` AS  `e` 
LEFT JOIN  `mg_customer_entity` AS  `o` ON e.customer_id = o.entity_id
WHERE e.created_at = o.created_at
GROUP BY YEAR( e.created_at ) , MONTH( e.created_at ) 
ORDER BY e.created_at DESC
)sub_query
```

Edit: to clarify I want a table to display:
Month - #New Customer Orders - #Existing Customer Orders - Total Customer Orders

A new customer would be a customer who came onto the site placed there first order in month x if they then came back and ordered in month a,b and c then those orders would be classed as existing customer orders

I have come across this script on this site but I'm not sure how that would help.

```
$LastOrder=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$LastOrdertime= $LastOrder->getCreatedAt();

$OrderCollection=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_email',$LastOrder->getData('customer_email'))
        ->setOrder('created_at','asc');
$fstoredetime= $OrderCollection->getFirstItem()->getCreatedAt();    

if($fstoredetime==$LastOrdertime):
// new customer
else:
//old customer
endif;
```

I can get number of transactions by month with this code but I want to split it out into new and existing customers

```
<?php
            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT count(*), created_at FROM sales_flat_order WHERE status NOT LIKE 'canceled' AND store_id BETWEEN 1 AND 2 GROUP BY YEAR(created_at), MONTH(created_at) ORDER BY created_at DESC");

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            $num = $row[0];

              echo "<tr>";

              echo "<td>";

              echo date("m/Y", strtotime($row['created_at']));

              echo "</td>";

              echo "<td>";

              echo $num;

              echo "</td>";

              echo "</tr>";
            }

            mysqli_close($con);
        ?>
```

I have also tried comparing created_at in both customer and order tables, has anyone done this before?

SOLUTION:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT e.grand_total, e.created_at, COUNT( e.increment_id ) AS grand_total1, o.entity_id, o.created_at AS  `last_order_date` 
FROM  `mg_sales_flat_order` AS  `e` 
LEFT JOIN  `mg_customer_entity` AS  `o` ON e.customer_id = o.entity_id
WHERE DATE(e.created_at) = DATE(o.created_at)
GROUP BY YEAR( e.created_at ) , MONTH( e.created_at ) 
ORDER BY created_at DESC
)sub_query
```

I also found more information here http://www.webamondo.co.uk/blog/magento-sql-repeat-customers-vs-new-customers/

Comment: How exactly do you want to define a "new" customer, as opposed to an "existing" one?

Comment: @Mike a new customer would just be a customer that hadn't ordered before.

Comment: Before when? Do you mean that a new customer is any customer at all that has exactly one order, and any customer with more than one order is "existing"?

Comment: @Mike If an order is placed in April and the customer had previously made no other order then they would be a new customer, if the customer placed in april but had previously ordered before then they would be an existing customer. So I would end up with a table that had the headers Month, Total transactions, New Cust Trans, Existing Cust Trans.

Comment: Is the "in April" part meaningful? What if they made that order (their only order) in December 2014? Do you still consider them new, or is it purely a function of counting their orders?

Comment: @Mike then that would a new customer in december, April was just an example

Comment: So, is a "new customer" a customer who has made their first order within the last 30 days, then? Before anyone can start to think of what code might look like, that has to be clearly defined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23338/discussion-between-will-wright-and-mike).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant tables and fields are

- sales_flat_order - customer_id, updated_at
- customer_entity - created_at

Just do a join of these two tables and then group as needed.

Comment: thanks david I have edited the script above which works sort of I just need WHERE e.created_at = o.created_at to just compare the date rather than date and time